# Moving old VB.NET Device Application (PDA) to C# Android Application

Tags: c#, android, .net, vb.net, xamarin

I received the task of converting an old project (made around 2005) which was targeting the `PDA devices`, to an `Android application`. The requirements were to change the already-existing code as little as possible. The bad part is that the provided code is written in `VB.NET` and it is heavily dependent on the GUI, so no real separation was made between these two parts back then. What is more, it is very little written in OOP style. After some research, I got to the conclusion that making a `Xamarin project` where I would have a separate project only for the VB.NET code, which would be a `class library project`, independent of the GUI, would be the best solution. Something like:

```
'method in my VB.NET project:'
Private Sub SomeButtonVB_Click([parameter list])
'code of the method independent of GUI'
End Sub

//the C# project, having a reference to the VB.NET project
//method in the C#/Xamarin project, connecting the VB.NET project with the GUI:
private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   SomeButtonVB_Click([parameter list]);
}
```

The methods in my `C# project`, which connect the backend with the GUI would only represent some **wrappers** for the methods in the `VB.NET project`, just like in the example above. The problem is, there are quite a few errors, due to the lack of existence of `Windows.Forms controls` in the `VB.NET project` (again, it's a **class library project**). My workaround would be to create equivalent classes for the most important controls, just to hold the data they would present on the GUI and send the required data back to the wrapper methods that would then display it on the visual controls.

I am quite sure this is still a very nonoptimal solution and there would be way too much work to do. As this is my first project of this type, I am not sure how to approach such a task, so I'd like to receive some opinions, maybe some links to some helpful articles, anything that might help. Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: Sorry, that's not helping you. But that's not a funny task... Good luck. I would personally agree with @MichaelRandall comment just below. If the architecture is a mess. Instead of trying to understand what it is doing and adding more complexity. I would say rewrite is also a solution...

Comment: "*The bad part is that the provided code is written in VB.NET and it is heavily dependent on the GUI*" - this sounds like a nightmare. If the original app was a mess architecturally, then there is no easy way to approach this problem, and everything will be layers of hack after hack. It would make more sense to just cut and run

Comment: @MichaelRandall What do you mean by "cut and run"?

Comment: Start over again, and engineer it from scratch, pull the bits in you can use

Comment: That's what I was thinking to do as well, it's way too much work to fix the mess that's there, would make it from scratch way faster